# Is there a way to find a value and set it as a reference within a formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 7 digit parent value referenced in column A that I need to use in a formula in column E. The parent value is followed by a random number of 4 digit child values and will reset with a new parent value. I need to reference the parent row in a formula that is child qty/parent qty without knowing the exact interval between child rows.

I am fairly new to VBA and 100% self taught. I have never used a variable within a formula before. I have pieced together the following code but I am having some problem referencing my key and placing the variable formula.

```
Sub FindRatio()
'

'
    Range("D2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'This is setting a Key in column D to Flag the parent
    '1= parent , 0 = child
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEN(RC[-3])>4,""1"",""0"")"
     Dim LastRow As Long
     'A = ID column
         LastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
         Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & LastRow)

With Range("D2:D" & LastRow)
    Set c = .Find(1, LookIn:=xlValues)
   If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            'formula to make child qty/parent qty
            c.Value = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]/R[-1]C[-2]"
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Cell A2 has the 7 digit parent ID with a quantity in C2. The child ID will be in the following A3:A7 cells with the quantities listed in cells C3:C7 with the second parent starting in row 8 on cell A8. I am trying to make the code in cell E3 (first child) be =C3/C2 and cell E4 (second child) be =C4/C2. This will continue though E7 and then reset the parent quantity upon the next parent ID. Cell E9 should be =C9/C8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following subroutine should compute the ratios you need:

```
Sub QuantityRatios()
    Dim N As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ParentQuantity As Long

    N = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For i = 2 To N
        If Len(Cells(i, 1)) = 7 Then
            ' This is a parent row, record note its quantity
            ParentQuantity = Cells(i, 3)
        Else
            ' This is a child row, divide its quantity by the parent's to get
            ' the ratio.
            Cells(i, 5) = Cells(i, 3) / ParentQuantity
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Or, if you'd prefer the cells to contain formulae instead of values, this subroutine should give you what you want:

```
Sub QuantityRatioFormulae()
    Dim N As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ParentRow As Long

    N = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For i = 2 To N
        If Len(Cells(i, 1)) = 7 Then
            ' This 1is a parent row, record which row it is.
            ParentRow = i
        Else
            Dim difference As Long

            ' Get the number of rows between this child and its parent.
            difference = ParentRow - i

            ' This is a child row, populate column E with a formula to calculate
            ' its
            Cells(i, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]/R[" & CStr(difference) & "]C[-2]"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Let's walk through them line by line, starting  with the first one (QuantityRatios):

```
Dim N as Long
Dim i as Long
Dim ParentQuantity as Long
```

Variable declarations aren't strictly necessary in VBA, but many consider them to be good form. We declare three variables here: `N`, `i`, and `ParentQuantity`. They're all of type `Long`, which stores a long integer (whole number) value. I'm running with the assumption that your quantities are all whole numbers. If not, use the type `Double` for your quantity variables. `N` will be the number of rows in your table. We'll use `i` to iterate through a `For` loop. `ParentQuantity` will store the quantity of the last parent we've encountered as we go through the table row by row.

```
N = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

`ActiveSheet` refers to the current worksheet in Excel. Excel keeps track of the portion of a worksheet which contains data and you can access it with `.UsedRange`. You can get the rows of a range using `.Rows` and, further, the count with `.Count`. Put it all together and we have an expression to compute the number of rows in the current worksheets used range - cool. We'll use that later.

```
For i = 2 to N
```

We already figured out how many rows are in your table and stored that number in `N`. From the description of your problem, it sounds like the data starts in row 2 (you probably have column titles in row 1?). So, to move through your table row by row, we want to start on row 2 and end on row N. `For` loops are great for this kind of problem. Within the loop, `i` will always have the value of the row we're currently looking at.

```
If Len(Cells(i, 1)) = 7 Then
```

We have a lot going on here. Let's start with the `Cells` function. `Range` is a great way to access a cell in the worksheet if you know its address ahead of time (like 'E2' or 'D5'). If you don't, you can use `Cells`. All you have to do is give it a row number and a column number and you can access that cell. That's what we're doing here: we're saying we want to see the value on row `i` (remember that `i` contains the current row's index) and in column 1 (aka column A), which contains parent/child values. Calling `Len` on that value will give us the length of the value. If it's 7, we know this is a parent row. Otherwise, it's a child row. The next line of code to be executed will depend on this.

```
ParentQuantity = Cells(i, 3)
```

Again, we're using `Cells` to access the worksheet. Specifically, column 3 (column C) of the `i`th row, which is the parent's quantity. That will be stored in `ParentQuantity` for later.

```
Cells(i, 5) = Cells(i, 3) / ParentQuantity
```

If the current row is a child, then this line is executed. The quantity is accessed in the same way (`Cells(i, 3)`) and then divided by `ParentQuantity` which contains the quantity of the last parent we found. That value is the ratio and is placed in column 5 (column E).

Alternatively, if you want the cells to contain formulas instead of just values, you can note the parent's row index as you pass (`ParentRow` in the second example). Concatenating the strings `"=RC[-2]/R["`, `"-1"`, and `"]C[-2]"` will yield a usable formula, `"=RC[-2]/R[-1]C[-2]"`. Therefore, we can just change that middle `"-1"` to whatever we want. Specifically, we want it to be the difference between the index of the current row and the row of the last parent.

I hope some of this helps you out. Good luck continuing to learn about VBA!

P.S. It's *always* a good idea to be careful with your indentation. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Frank, Thank you for looking at my problem. I walked through your post and the code ran over 6,000 lines perfectly. The description that you provided was easy to read and provided reasoning behind what you wrote. Thank you again for your help! Cheers!